# Alias in select yields

Tags: alias

Running a simple query like the following yields "Error Code: 1054, Unknown column 'GDP_PPP' in 'field list'

```
SELECT
COUNTRY
, POPULATION
, GDP_PPP_MIL
, GDP_PPP_MIL * 1E6 AS GDP_PPP
, GDP_PPP / POPULATION
FROM COUNTRIES
```

I am using mysql v5.7.12 and MySQL Workbench 6.3 on OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan).  I just downloaded it a few days ago, then upgraded the OS to El Cap.

Answer (score 1):

The column you just naming(alias) would not reflect in the query

Some alternatives

1.to use the formula again

```
SELECT
COUNTRY
, POPULATION
, GDP_PPP_MIL
, GDP_PPP_MIL * 1E6 AS GDP_PPP
, GDP_PPP_MIL * 1E6/ POPULATION
FROM COUNTRIES
```

Comment: So does MySQL not support aliases? I want to use the alias in an order by statement and in another instance in an over partition.

Comment: You can use alias in order by query in the same select query only limitation for select query is in the select columns alias cannot be used to calculate other select columns @TSB

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
SELECT COUNTRY , POPULATION , GDP_PPP_MIL , GDP_PPP_MIL * 1E6 AS 'GDP_PPP' , GDP_PPP / POPULATION FROM COUNTRIES
```